# javascript regex exclude character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like this

a b:_c

a:_c

The regex that I am using is `/:(.*)/g` , but it also captures ':_'

**I want to achieve-->** c

**What I've got-->** :_c

How do I exclude them?

P.S.: replaced *space* with *underscore*, for easy understanding.

EDIT: I want to capture everything behind ': '

EDIT2: here is [regexr](http://regexr.com/3gekv) with text, as u can see, it also captures ': '

Comment: A period matches any character, `[a-zA-Z]` would match the alphabet.

Comment: It requires a clearer description. Do you want to capture a single character at the end of the line, that is preceded by a colon and space? Or...

Comment: Can you post a code example of what you've done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: If you care about comments you will find your way.

Comment: @revo i do care bout comments, I'm testing every solutions that have been suggested here

Comment: Your one and only problem is ignoring *capturing groups* which without them you wouldn't be able to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `/:\s(.*)/g`.

That will capture a single space after a `:` before starting to capture:

```
a b: c => "c"
a: c   => "c"
```

```js
var re = /:\s(.*)/;

var tests = [
    'a: c',
    'a: cat',
    'b a: test',
    'a: c',
    'Test: this is the rest of the sentence',
];

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    console.log('TEST: ', '"' + tests[i] + '"');
    console.log('RESULT: "' + tests[i].match(re)[1] + '"');
}
```

**Note:** You ***must*** get the first capture group from the match. If you do not, you will not get the desired result. See [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression#432503) for information on how to do this.

Comment: You need to get the first captured group. See my latest edits.

Comment: `:\s(.*)` absolutely doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: @revo, it absolutely does answer the question. Note the text of the OP's question: *P.S.: replaced space with dash, for easy understanding.*

Comment: It's not a *dash* it's called *underscore*, firstly. Second, I was referring to *...everything after character `:` so result will start from **letters**.* part of requirements which by now is removed / re-phrased by original poster.

Comment: @SumnerEvans i want capture everything behind the :_ , not just single c

Comment: @revo, yes the OP used the wrong terminology. My answer now does capture everything after `: `.

Comment: @user1898714, have you tried running the snippet I included in my answer?

Comment: @SumnerEvans yes, still not exactly what i needed, sry for wrong requirements :<

i want to capture everything behind ": ", till the end of sentence.

Comment: Your main problem is not knowing what [capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/660/capture-groups#t=201707271903279175358) are and [how one can access them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression). @user1898714

Comment: @user1898714, I have updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear. You *must* grab the first capture group to get the result you want.

Comment: @SumnerEvans damn, it captures only first letter, not even word :c

Comment: @user1898714, did you copy-paste *directly* from my answer? When I run it using the "Run code snippet" button here on StackOverflow, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that underscore will always prefix the `c` you could do this:
`/:_?(.*)/g`

The `_?` matches 0 or 1 underscores, so you will only get `c` as a result.

```js
console.log('a b:_c'.match(/:_?(.*)/)[1])
```

Comment: still captures ':_'

Comment: @user1898714 you are probably looking at the full match, you want to look at group 1. Run the snippet I added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the string "c" or the last character?

```
var a = "a:_c a b:_c";

/c/g.exec(a)

/.$/g.exec(a)
```

Edit to match comment:

Use the following to remove everything before and including ":_"

```
a.replace(/.*:_*/, '')
```

For space:

```
a.replace(/.*:\s*/, '')
```

Comment: everything behind ': '